# There is no ViewData item of type 'IEnumerable<SelectListItem>'

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, viewdata

I have an issue the same with others I already tried their solution but none of it solve my problem.
The error shows:

> There is no ViewData item of type 'IEnumerable' that
>   has the key 'doctorroleID

after 'Submit', the error shows up but the data is being stored in the database completely.

This is my View:

```
<div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.doctorroleID, "doctorroleID", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.DropDownList("doctorroleID", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.doctorroleID, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
</div>
```

This is my controller:

```
public ActionResult Create()
        {  ViewBag.doctorroleID = new SelectList(db.DoctorRoles, "doctorroleID", "doctorrole1");

            return View();
        }

        // POST: Doctor/Create
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Create(DoctorProfile doctor, AdminProfile admin)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                using (var db = new eoperadbEntities())
                {
                    var crypto = new SimpleCrypto.PBKDF2();
                    var encrpPass = crypto.Compute(doctor.password);
                    var sysUser = db.DoctorProfiles.Create();

                    sysUser.doctorlastname = doctor.doctorlastname;
                    sysUser.doctorfirstname = doctor.doctorfirstname;
                    sysUser.doctormiddlename = doctor.doctormiddlename;
                    sysUser.doctorcontactnumber1 = doctor.doctorcontactnumber1;
                    sysUser.doctorcontactnumber2 = doctor.doctorcontactnumber2;
                    sysUser.doctoremail = doctor.doctoremail;

                    sysUser.doctorroleID = doctor.doctorroleID;
                    sysUser.doctorimage = doctor.doctorimage;

                    sysUser.username = doctor.username;
                    sysUser.password = encrpPass;
                    sysUser.passwordSalt = crypto.Salt;
                    sysUser.status = "Active";

                    db.DoctorProfiles.Add(sysUser);
                    db.SaveChanges();

                    var log = db.AccountsLogs.Create();
                    var doctorID = db.DoctorProfiles.Where(a => a.username == doctor.username).FirstOrDefault();
                    log.accountaffectedid = doctor.doctorID;
                    log.accountslogID = admin.adminID;
                    log.date = DateTime.Now;
                    log.operation = "Create";
                    db.AccountsLogs.Add(log);
                    db.SaveChanges();
                }
                ModelState.Clear();
                ViewBag.Message = doctor.username + "Successfully registered!";
            }
            return View();
        }
```

Comment: Because you have not set the value of `ViewBag.doctorroleID` in the POST method before you return the view so its `null`

Comment: how? Im sorry, I am new to this.

Comment: Exactly the same as you did in the GET method.

Comment: And exactly the same issue as the dupe (just a slightly different error message because you use `DropDownList()` rather than `DoprDownListFor()`